# Force directed layout

Tags: javascript, svg, force-layout

when i use [THIS](https://github.com/jackrusher/jssvggraph) algorithm to calculate force directed layout of graph where from 1 node is 10 or more edges, calculation failed.
I guess it's because calculated position is so much large and it's represented as "NaN".

Input data:

```
var g = new Graph("canvas", 960, 700 );
            g.createVertex("a");
            g.createVertex("a1");
            g.createVertex("a2");
            g.createVertex("a3");
            g.createVertex("a4");
            g.createVertex("a5");
            g.createVertex("a6");
            g.createVertex("a7");
            g.createVertex("a8");
            g.createVertex("a9");
            g.createVertex("a10");
            g.createVertex("a11");
            g.createVertex("a12");
            g.createVertex("a13");
            g.createVertex("a14");
            g.createVertex("a15");
            g.createVertex("a16");


            g.createEdge("a","a1");
            g.createEdge("a","a2");
            g.createEdge("a","a3");
            g.createEdge("a","a4");
            g.createEdge("a","a5");
            g.createEdge("a","a6");
            g.createEdge("a","a7");
            g.createEdge("a","a8");
            g.createEdge("a","a9");
            g.createEdge("a","a10");
            g.createEdge("a","a11");
            g.createEdge("a","a12");
            g.createEdge("a","a13");
            g.createEdge("a","a14");
            g.createEdge("a","a15");
            g.createEdge("a","a16");
            g.go();
```

When i use this data, sometimes is graph rendered without problems, but mostly it breaks.

Can someone help me to fix it?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In the link you provided, the third example has something like:

```
g.repulsion = g.repulsion / 8;
            g.spring_length = 1;
```

This apparently makes it more compact. Since, you want to spread out the graph, you should probably multiply like this:

```
g.repulsion = g.repulsion * 10;
```

Try different numbers to see if it works. In future, I would suggest to use something with better documentation like D3.js.

Comment: I tried use different values for repulsion, but without effect. Existing some library which will calculate force directed and return data? Or simply working exmaple of calculating force directed?

Comment: @1000Bugy If you are asking if D3.js can calculate directed force vectors, I am not sure. But, you can check D3 docs.